# right join with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
stores = [[232, '2016-02-05 04:30:00', 'Test User', 1],
          [332, '2016-02-06 04:30:00', 'Test User', 2],
          [432, '2016-02-07 04:30:00', 'Test User', 3],
          [532, '2016-02-08 04:30:00', 'Test User', 4],
          [632, '2016-02-09 04:30:00', 'Test User', 5]]

visits = pd.DataFrame(data=stores, columns=['store', 'visit', 'auditor', 'scene'])
visits.set_index(['store', 'visit'], inplace=True)
scenes = [[1, 1551, 2],
          [5, 1661, 4]]

scenes = pd.DataFrame(data=scenes, columns=['scene', 'product', 'amount'])
scenes.set_index('scene', inplace=True)

store_with_products = pd.merge(visits, scenes, left_on='scene', right_index=True, how='right')
```

The result that I get looks following:

```
                             auditor  scene  product  amount
store visit                                                 
232   2016-02-05 04:30:00  Test User      1     1551       2
632   2016-02-09 04:30:00  Test User      5     1661       4
```

But I am doing `right join` why I not get full stores matrix padded with `NAN` where relevant data is missing with scenes matrix ?
How I can fix above ?

Comment: What is your desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a left join, not right join.  Then it works:

```
                             auditor  scene  product  amount
store visit                                                 
232   2016-02-05 04:30:00  Test User      1   1551.0     2.0
332   2016-02-06 04:30:00  Test User      2      NaN     NaN
432   2016-02-07 04:30:00  Test User      3      NaN     NaN
532   2016-02-08 04:30:00  Test User      4      NaN     NaN
632   2016-02-09 04:30:00  Test User      5   1661.0     4.0
```